# Module not found in office-js

Tags: typescript, office-js, office-addins

It is my second day learning office-js. I looked at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins), for some code samples. But I don't see that there is anything special about modules. Now I try to create a more complex program, so I want to spread my code over multiple files.

I created a project using this command: `yo office --projectType taskpane --name "test1" --host excel --ts true`

Then I modified the `src/taskpane/taskpane.ts` file like that:

```
import { runExcel } from "src/utils/run-excel";
import { clearWorkbook } from "src/utils/clear-workbook";

Office.onReady((info) => {
  if (info.host === Office.HostType.Excel) {
    document.getElementById("sideload-msg").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("app-body").style.display = "flex";
    document.getElementById("clearWorkbook").onclick = () => runExcel(clearWorkbook);
  }
});
```

And I created those 2 files:

```
// src/utils/clear-workbook.ts
export async function clearWorkbook(context: Excel.RequestContext): Promise<Excel.Worksheet> {
    const newWorksheet: Excel.Worksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.add();
    newWorksheet.activate();
  
    const sheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
    sheets.load("items/name,items/id");
    await context.sync();
  
    for (let i in sheets.items) {
      const worksheet = sheets.items[i];
      if(newWorksheet.id !== worksheet.id) {
        worksheet.delete();
      }
    }
  
    return newWorksheet;
  }
```

```
// src/utils/run-excel.ts
export async function runExcel(callback: (context: Excel.RequestContext) => Promise<unknown>) {
    try {
      await Excel.run(async (context: Excel.RequestContext) => {
        await callback(context);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

But I get the following error:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./src/taskpane/taskpane.ts 6:18-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'src/utils/run-excel' in 'C:\Users\ymonb\code\test1\src\taskpane'

ERROR in ./src/taskpane/taskpane.ts 7:23-58
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'src/utils/clear-workbook' in 'C:\Users\ymonb\code\test1\src\taskpane'
```

The code seems to be working fine if I put all my functions in the same file. It's only when I use the import/export functionality that the error appears.

Why?

Comment: This seems to be a problem with TypeScript, not Office Add-ins. The error is probably literally true: there may be something wrong with the path in your `import` statements. Try `import { runExcel } from "./src/utils/run-excel";`

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you need to use `../utils/run-excel` and `../utils/clear-workbook`.  (your inside of the `src/taskpane` folder, going out into `src/` and then into `utils` and then finally into the files)

Typescript thinks that your trying to go into `/src/taskpane/src/utils/run-excel` and `/src/taskpane/src/utils/clear-workbook`.